# I am trying to print a txt file and it doesn't work in C homework

Tags: c, file

I'm writing code that's supposed to verify that a .txt file is a certain format.

I wrote my code as I saw in a tutorial and in the website
and for some reason my program doesn't even print my file.
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
The code will do something far more complex, but I'm still trying to work on my basics.

Here's my code so far:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
/* argv[0] = name of my running file
 * argv[1] = the first file that i receive
 */
define MAXBUFLEN 4096

char source[MAXBUFLEN + 1];
int badReturnValue = 1;
char *error = "Error! trying to open the file ";
if (argc != 2) {
    printf("please supply a file \n");
    return badReturnValue;
}
char *fileName = argv[1];


FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r"); /* "r" = open for reading */
if (fp != NULL) {
    size_t newLen = fread(&source, sizeof(char), MAXBUFLEN, fp);
    if (ferror(fp) != 0) {
        printf("%s %s", error, fileName);
        return badReturnValue;
    }
    int symbol;

    while ((symbol = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        putchar(symbol);


    }
    printf("finish");

    fclose(fp);
}

else {
    printf("%s %s", error, fileName);
    return badReturnValue;
}
```

}

Comment: i tried to be according the format, hope i managed

Comment: and i just to ensure i am not writing wrong code before i continue

Comment: Why are you calling `fopen` twice? No need for that. Also don't return `-1`. Return a positive value instead, like `1`, on failure.

Comment: you are right, i fixed this ones, and edites my code, for some reason i still have the same issues, seems like im missinf somthing here

Comment: How big is your text file?

Comment: i dont know. i can do it with out a buffer but i always use one when i work with files. but i saw that if i remove all the syntax:

Comment: size_t newLen = fread(&source, sizeof(char), MAXBUFLEN, fp);
        if (ferror(fp) != 0) {
            printf("%s %s", error, fileName);//todo check weather this shit even work
            return badReturnValue;
        }

Comment: it works, i still try to figure out why, any way thnx u guys trying to help with this...

Comment: If you want to read the contents of the file with `fread`, then you need to print the contents of the file from the buffer. Example: `for (int i=0;i<newLen;i++) putchar(source[i]);` Using `fread` is fine if the whole file fits into your buffer. But for a large file, you should use `fgets` to read one line at a time.

Comment: so i worked on my file while i were suppose to work on my buufer all this time?

Comment: Yes, after you read the contents of the file into the buffer, you need to work on the buffer.

Comment: ohh i see, i think i were a bit over killing it, but this how you learn. you are great! thnx...

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a bit more explanations:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

// there might be a macro BUFLEN defined in stdio
// which size is optimized for reading in chunks.
// Test if avaiable otherwise define it
#ifndef BUFLEN
#   define BUFLEN 4096
#endif
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  char source[BUFLEN];
  char *filename;
  FILE *fp;
  size_t fpread, written;
  char c;
  int ret_fclose;

  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // reset errno, just in case
  errno = 0;

  // work on copy
  filename = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
  if (filename == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Allocating %zu bytes failed\n", strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  filename = strcpy(filename, argv[1]);

  // try to open the file at 'filename'
  fp = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Opening file \"%s\" filename failed\n", filename);
    // errno might got set to something usable, check and print
    if (errno != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // You have two options here. One is to read in chunks of MAXBUFLEN
  while ((fpread = fread(&source, 1, BUFLEN, fp)) > 0) {
    // Do something with the stuff we read into "source"
    // we do nothing with it here, we just write to stdout
    written = fwrite(&source, 1, fpread, stdout);
    // you can use 'written' for error check when writing to an actual file
    // but it is unlikely (but not impossible!) with stdout

    // test if we wrote what we read
    if ((fpread - written) != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "We did not write what we read. Diff: %d\n",
          (int) (fpread - written));
    }
  }
  // fread() does not distinguish between EOF and error, we have to check by hand
  if (feof(fp)) {
    // we have read all, exit
    puts("\n\n\tfinish\n");
    // No, wait, we want to do it again in a different way, so: no exit
    // exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  } else {
    // some error may have occured, check
    if (ferror(fp)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Something bad happend while reading \"%s\"\n", filename);
      if (errno != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      }
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }

  // the other way is to read it byte by byte

  // reset the filepointers/errors et al.
  rewind(fp);
  // rewind() should have reseted errno, but better be safe than sorry
  errno = 0;
  printf("\n\n\tread and print \"%s\" again\n\n\n\n", filename);

  // read one byte and print it until end of file
  while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    // just print. Gathering them into "source" is left as an exercise
    fputc(c, stdout);
  }

  // clean up
  errno = 0;
  ret_fclose = fclose(fp);
  // even fclose() might fail
  if (ret_fclose == EOF) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Something bad happend while closing \"%s\"\n", filename);
    if (errno != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // The macros EXIT_FAILURE and EXIT_SUCCESS are set to the correct values for
  // the OS to tell it if we had an eror or not.

  // Using exit() is noot necessary here but there exits teh function atexit()
  // that runs a given function (e.g: clean up, safe content etc.) when called
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: very helpful!thnx!

Answer (score 1):

You read from the file *twice* but only print *once*.

If the file is to small the first reading will read all of the contents, and the second reading will not produce anything so you don't print anything.

Comment: thnx! i did as follow, (i just saw i put all my comments as well) and i still cant manange to print the file

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to reset the pointer after using fread.

Try fseek(fp, SEEK_SET, 0) to reset the pointer to the beginning of the file. Then print the file.